# Can my recommendation letters be repeated?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, research-undergraduate

For example, if I am going to apply to 3 REU programs that ask me for 2 recommendation letters each one.

Can my 2 professors who I asked the recommendation letters send the exact same letters to the 3 REU programs?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, they can.  Sometimes letter writers make minor changes to the letters, for example to add information specific to a given program, but this sort of fine tuning is optional (and almost nobody makes major changes).  The default is to send the same letter.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they can send the exact same letter. In fact, trying to come up with a new letter for each individual program can be overly burdensome.

I would, however, make sure that your letter writers either make no specific mention to the individual programs or make sure they change them appropriately. If one of your letters to program X says "This student would make a fantastic addition to program Y," then a reviewer at program X might be turned off to your application. I don't think it's as bad as mentioning program Y in your SOP (where you have complete control of what is said) to program X, but it's an error to be avoided if possible.